# How to mention height and Width in terms of percentage in size() in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

How do I mention `size(350,450)` in terms of percentages in `wxpython`?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# gotoclass.py
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, 
            size=(390, 350))
        self.InitUI()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show()     

    def InitUI(self):
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        font = wx.SystemSettings_GetFont(wx.SYS_SYSTEM_FONT)
        font.SetPointSize(9)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        st1 = wx.StaticText(panel, label='Class Name')
        st1.SetFont(font)
        hbox1.Add(st1, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=8)
        tc = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
        hbox1.Add(tc, proportion=1)
        vbox.Add(hbox1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.TOP, border=10)

        vbox.Add((-1, 10))
        panel.SetSizer(vbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Example(None, title='Go To Class')
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the screen resolution using `wx.GetDisplaySize()`. Compute the percentage in pixels. Set the size by `self.SetSize()` later, not in the constructor but before `self.Show()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can only specify the size of widgets in wxPython by pixel size. See http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Size-class.html for more information. You cannot pass percentages to it. On the other hand, you can sort of do percentages with widgets inside sizers as sizers support the idea of proportion. But I don't believe that is what you really want.